# OBSOLETE - ActionStack - An ActionScript Wrapper for the API

Tags: library, obsolete, flash

> ### Obsolete - designed for a decommissioned version of the API and most of the links, below, are dead.

[image]

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

*Here is a simple example that fetches stats on Stack Overflow:*

```
import com.actionstack.ActionStack;
import com.actionstack.QueryCompleteEvent;

var actionStack:ActionStack = new ActionStack("stackoverflow",
                                              "");

actionStack.addEventListener(QueryCompleteEvent.QUERY_COMPLETE,ProcessResults);

actionStack.StatsMethod();

private function ProcessResults(event:QueryCompleteEvent):void
{
    var data:Object = event.GetValue();
            
    var stats:Object = data["statistics"];
    stats = stats[0];

    // You can now access the data in stats
    // like stats["total_questions"]
}
```

### About

ActionStack is an ActionScript 3 wrapper for the StackOverflow API. ActionStack fully supports **all** API methods, including StackAuth methods. Although there is no documentation for ActionStack at the moment, the examples above and in the repository should clear up any confusion.

#### Examples

> Dead link: <del>**Stats example: http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/actionstack/simple.html**</del>
> Dead link: <del>**User example: http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/actionstack/user.html**</del>

#### License

StackScript is released under the MIT license.

#### Download

*No packages as of yet.*

#### Platform

The packages should compile in ActionScript 3+. Consequently, the SWF files should work with the Flash Player 9+.

### Contact

I can be reached at admin@quickmediasolutions.com

### Code

The code and example can be found at http://launchpad.net/actionstack

Comment: So this is what your "A" in a shredder was for! Nice work, as always

Comment: @Matt: Thanks! Did you get a chance to look at the demo? Specifically [this](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/actionstack/user.html) one.

Comment: ++ hmmm.... great idea. you know i am going to chase you on this one, right? once i get the soapi.js RC finished i am just going to have to port it to actionscript. i have long been waiting for an excuse to write some flash.

Comment: @code: The API is relatively stable - why have an automatic code generator do what I've already taken the time to do? Try using my wrapper and you won't be disappointed. It comes with extra utility functions too. And besides, if you want to write some Flash, write an app that uses my wrapper :)

Comment: the code generation phase of soapi is closed. with the changes slowed to a crawl, i am now refining the library and adding the higher level functionality. the point is not to try and one-up you, it is to provide a consistent programming experience across multiple platforms.  I am still a several weeks at best from having time to tool up and switch focus to flash, so the glory is all yours. like I said, great idea. r.e. codegen: soapi codegen will resume when 2.0 goes into beta. soapi watch will continue to monitor the api.

Comment: @code: Oh boy, just thinking about 2.0 makes me excited :) Can't wait to write that answering bot.